# CSS3 border radius shorthand solution

Tags: css, shorthand

Is this

```
border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
```

A shortend version that will work with all browsers that recognise it to this:

```
border-top-left-radius:10px; border-top-right-radius:10px;
```

Comment: Why don't you try it? Which takes about the same amount of time to write this question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's better the first approach because it's shorter and waste less bandwith.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are identical just like there is padding-left there is border-top-left-radius.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the confidence of knowing that it will work on all the browsers that can support it, you should be using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/border_radius/).