# How to change the bottom border radius?

Tags: css

So, i checked on googlehow to do it, some people tell me the code is:

```
border-bottom-radius: value;
```

ON CHROME* of course.
well i tried and it seems that doesnt work.
if you guys could help me, i'm here, waiting for your help! thanks :D

Comment: Googling border-bottom-radius... third result: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/

Comment: For complete Browser Support take a look at http://borderradius.com/

Comment: Use this **border-bottom-left-radius:value** and **border-bottom-right-radius:value**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`
<strike>use `border-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius`</strike>

Or use the shorthand notation, as describe at [CSS3 border radius shorthand solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249648/css3-border-radius-shorthand-solution), for instance:

```
border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
```

Comment: yes, you are right :) i mean: use `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

```
border-bottom-left-radius: value;
border-bottom-right-radius: value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `border-bottom-right-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius`.

The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) is wonderful reference and my first stop for questions like these.